# Is querystring is faster to read than a cookie?

Tags: xml, performance, cookies, query-string

I am developing a web application and I am encrypting some XML and passing the result to a query string.

The question is: if I store the XML in a cookie instead of using the query string, would it be faster? My application is not slow, I am just wondering about the performance difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't prematurely micro-optimise. If you care about performance, then profile your code and deal with the bits that are actually slow instead of worrying about details like this. (Especially since cookies and query strings have far more important differentiating factors that should be used to choose between them — cookies persist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no difference whatsoever. Both querystring and cookies are parsed from raw HTTP request into respective .NET objects for you and thus accessing cookie is no different than accessing a querystring value.

Comment: Who said anything about .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Both the cookie and query string are included in the request body, so neither will give you an advantage as you are, from the coding side, query collections in the Request body.